# Designed table cannot be saved in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to design a table in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
I can modify it but cannot be saved, anyone knows the problem how to fix?

[image]

Comment: Details, Details... I'm guessing you get an error message? if so, what is it?

Comment: You may as well have said "I have a problem, does anyone know how to fix it?" and nothing else. What error are you getting, what are you modifying. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Well, if you create a modify script, you should be able to run it and save. Like @ZoharPeled said, what error are you getting?

Comment: look at the screenshot!

Comment: The error message is pretty clear what the problem is and how to fix - what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to fix.

Go to  **tools > options > designers** uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation